# Windows 7 tablet and external cd-rom

Tags: windows, tablet, external-drive

Seeing all this cool guys with their tablets, my mother decided that she also need one. But, of course, she want to do the same stuff as with her old notebook. In particular she is playing bridge with special (windows) bridge software that comes on a cd-rom and has a copy protection. You have to insert the CD once in a while if you want to start the program.

Is it possible to connect an external cd or dvd drive via usb to a Windows 7 tablet like the *Acer ICONIA Tab W500* and does typically all standard Windows software (i386) also run on a windows 7 tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - Iconia Tab is a bog standard Windows based machine and as such will support all the normal USB functions of a non tablet computer.

However, you may also have some luck with Virtual CD Mounting software such as [Sly Soft Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/download.html) if it is just basic protection/requires the CD, or [Daemon Tools](http://www.filehippo.com/download_daemon_tools/) if it requires something advanced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to be careful which windows tablet I buy or will it work with anyone?

Comment: Anyone that have an USB port ...

Comment: As @aleroot said, but to expand slightly, any tablet  is a normal x86/x64 device should work just as well as a standard computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can attach an USB drive and work even with a standard Windows software .